# Tomcat unpack wars into directory other than appBase

Tags: deployment, tomcat6, symbolic-link

We would like to configure Tomcat in the following way (where `X` -SL-> `Y` represents a symlink named `X` pointing to a path `Y`):

- `CATALINA_HOME/webapps` -SL-> `/var/data/nas/deploymentconfiguration_a`
- `/var/data/nas/deploymentconfiguration_a/myapp.war` -SL-> `/var/data/nas/wars/app1.war`

The idea is to be able to configure which applications are deployed on a particular Tomcat instance by having a series of symlinks to WARs in a *deployment configuration* folder, and having anoher symlink named webapps from CATALINA_HOME to a particular *deployment configuration* folder.

Many Tomcat instances would point to the same *deployment configuration* folder.

I hope that's clear :S

The whole `/var/data/nas` tree would be read-only.

In trials, the main problem we are running up against is that Tomcat is obviously trying to explode the war into the *deployment configuration* folder (which it considers to be `appBase`), which is read only.

Is there a way to get Tomcat to unpack its wars into some kind of local work folder (I don't think there is, based upon a quick scan through the source code), or is the only way to proceed to stop Tomcat from exploding the war files in the first place?

We are using Tomcat 6.

## Edit

We are going to be running multiple Tomcat instances against the same configuration. So there could be 10 Tomcats running against `deploymentconfiguration_a` and 10 against `deploymentconfiguration_b`, but there could be some commonality between the actual WAR files in each *deployment configuration* (ie `deploymentconfiguration_a` could have WARs 1, 2 and 5 while `deploymentconfiguration_b` could have WARs 1, 5 and 7).

The reason it is RO is to avoid accidental modification of a particular configuration, and also to avoid one instance of Tomcat treading on the toes of another.

Comment: Can you describe a bit more your Tomcat "instances"? Are you running multiple Tomcats against a given set of files? Or are there multiple Tomcats running multiple different apps on from your NAS? And why does it have to be R/O?

Comment: Would having multiple <Host> declarations with different appBase attributes help alleviate the problem?

Comment: Also, is there a reason you are running multiple Tomcat instead of having one Tomcat with multiple <Service> entries?

Comment: re: the question about running multiple Tomcat vs multiple <Service> entries, not all Tomcat instances are on the same hardware.

Comment: re: multiple <Host> declarations, we are trying to standardise the configuration of the Tomcat instances so that we only have to create the correct symlink in order to correctly deploy a new Tomcat instance. Perhaps we could symlink to the correct configuration file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you've given me (and thanks for batting back and forth with me). I think these are your options:

1. Insert a unpackWars="false" into the Host directive within your server.xml file and run the apps directly from the war files.
2. Manually expand the wars on your nas into the proper deployment directories.

I give either of those recommendations only based on the fact that the file system where these deployments are going would be read only for the Tomcats involved.

I would personally go with option #1. Unless you need to see the individual files for some reason, there's no good reason to run with the files expanded.  (Unless of course you've got a bad application that needs to reference files within the war...)

I might also go so far as to also put autoDeploy="off". Unless you think you are going to be changing the war files underneath these groups of Tomcats on the spot?